# MySQL Connector: which is faster ...WHERE NOT EXISTS... or previous select?

Tags: mysql, mysql-connector

I'm using `mysql.connector` for python and I'm having a problem with a where not exists sub query inside a thread. I have the folowing template query:

```
 insert into table
    (a , b, c, cat_id, d)
    SELECT * FROM (SELECT '%s' as a, NOW() as b,
                    2 as c,%s as cat_id,
                    '%s' as d)
                as tmp
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        select * from table 
        where 
            cat_id = %s and
            d = '%s'
     ) LIMIT 1;
```

Being executed in multiple threads simultaneosly with a lot of different data. But it's overwhelming my database, the queries take a long time to execute and it gets slow to access the database witch is locking my other queries.
My question is: Using `mysql.connector`, would be faster to first try and query for the data (`SELECT * FROM table where cat_id = %s and d = '%s'`) and then, if it doesnt find any row, try to insert or it'll be even worst and take longer?

fyi, this is my table:

```
table(
   a varchar(30) null,
   b datetime not null,
   c int null,
   cat_id foreigh key,
   d varchar(30)
)
```

mysql server: 5.17

python 3.7

Comment: `%s` shouldn't be in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to add a unique index and use `INSERT IGNORE`:

```
ALTER TABLE table ADD UNIQUE INDEX (cat_id, d);

INSERT IGNORE INTO table (a, b, c, cat_id, d)
VALUES (%s, NOW(), 2, %s, %s);
```

Also, placeholders shouldn't be in quotes. You should put the values in the second argument to `cursor.execute()`, and it will quote them as needed.

Comment: If you use `printf` to fill in the placeholders, you need the quotes and you are risking "SQL injection".

Comment: I updated the question to say that they should be using `cursor.execute()` to fill in the parameters, not `.format()`.